# When does the Ardor - NXT to Ignis snapshot occur and which exchanges support the snapshot?

Tags: exchanges, nxt, ardor, ignis

I heard the Ignis snapshot is going to occur sometime in the summer of 2017. When is the exact date? And how many coins do you get for holding your NXT for Ignis? And which exchanges are on board with issuing the Ignis tokens?

Comment: Any idea if exchanges are supporting? Or do we need a seperate wallet?

Comment: might be safer to hold it in your own wallet when the snapshot occurs. unless you trust the exchanges will honor the coins you control. not worth the risk to leave it on an exchange.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No set date for release yet but with in the next few months. 1NXT will get you 0.5IGNIS.

Comment: Welcome!  Just so you know, your answer is being downvoted because it's a one-line answer that doesn't really answer the whole question.  People here tend to like answers with some context and explanation.  At the very least, you could cite your source.

Comment: This answer should be a comment instead.